# Failed to find selector => 9 when migrating project structure

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Trying to Migrate a Project Structure of my Angular 7 application to enable NativeScript following:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project#migrating-project-structure

When running `ng add @nativescript/schematics`, I get the following error:

`Failed to find selector => 9 in /apps/my-app/src/app/components/index.ts.`

My /apps/my-app/src/app/components/index.ts:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const APP_COMPONENTS: any[] = [
  AppComponent,
];

export * from './app.component';
```

The error is quite cryptic, not sure there's anything wrong with the way my index.ts is structured.

Help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of NS and cli?

Comment: Your @angular/cli install should be at 6.1.0 or newer.

Comment: Angular CLI: 7.3.8

Comment: tns --version
5.4.0